# Minikube service equivalent in EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, minikube, amazon-eks

When i run a cluster on Minikube i run:

```
> Minikube service <service-name>
```

To have the service address.

Which is the same command when running a cluster in AWS EKS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None. Refer https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-kubernetes-services-cluster/

Or just use https://github.com/txn2/kubefwd if you need quick access for dev purposes.